# babel-plugin-react-css-modules does not change class name in style tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I want to use `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` to create unique class names, so I did a PoC: I ejected create-ract-app, then I add `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` to plugins in package.json:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "babel-plugin-react-css-modules"
    ]
  },
```

When I start application I see that class in HTML is set correctly, but inside `<style>` tag it's regular `.App` name:

[image]

Am I missing something? I think it should be pretty easy to set up and I make some stupid mistake I can't see. Thank you in advance for every answer.

Edit: App.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div styleName="App">
      Test app
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Rant**: One of the many reasons I'm against the `create-react-app` (CRA) is because of how inflexible it can be when it comes to **customization**. If you're looking to include features, I'd recommend creating your own webpack configuration. Why? You'll become more familiar with Webpack, how to configure it, how to work within its limits, and how to add/change/adjust packages to your needs.

That said, the CRA comes preconfigured with both global and local (module) CSS imports and it conflicts with `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` (BPRCM). The CRA expects `.css` files without `module.css` to be normal global imports. Meanwhile, BPRCM expects `.css` files to be local imports. Not only is that a conflict, but the `localIdentName`s are mismatched. By default, CRA looks for `App.module.css` where `module.css` specifies it's a modulated import, like so: `import { App } from "./App.module.css";`. As such it assigns localIdentNames as `[file/folder]_[local]_[hash]` as mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dev-utils#getcssmodulelocalidentcontext-object-localidentname-string-localname-string-options-object-string), [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent.js#L35) and within an ejected `config/webpack.config.js` (Lines 432-456 -- it utilizes the `react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent` package).

In order to resolve these conflicts, you'll need to establish a `localIdentName` (by default BPCRM uses this `generateScopedName`: [[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#options) (4th option in the table), so I'll be using it for my example below), then you'll need to add BPRCM to the `webpack.config.js` under `babel-loader` because the CRA doesn't look for a babel configuration, then you'll have to remove the CSS module imports rule, and lastly, you'll need to add some options to their global CSS rule to make it local and utilize the `localIdentName`.

---

**Here's a working example**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules

**To utilize the repo above**:

- open a terminal window on the `~/Desktop` and clone the repo: `git clone git@github.com:mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules.git`
- cd into the `cra-css-modules` folder and type `yarn install` or `npm install`
- type `yarn start` or `npm start` to run the example

**What I changed**:

- Declared a [localIdentName](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L50) to match BPRCM's default scoped class name (**you can change this name to whatever you like and it'll still work with the example repo above**).
- Added [BPRCM](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L377-L382) to the `babel-loader` rule.
- Added a [modules](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L444-L447) configuration to switch the global CSS rule to a local CSS rule
- Removed the [local modules CSS rule](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L455-L470).
- Changed all `classNames` to `styleName` in the [App.js](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules/blob/master/src/App.js#L7-L22) file.

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) I simplified your solution a little bit: I removed 2nd step (`require.resolve("react-css-modules"...`). I will attach bounty to your answer when this option will be available.